# OneDrive web and 1st PC synced but the 2nd one doesn't

Tags: onedrive

I have a laptop (Windows 11) and a PC (Windows 10) which both sync to an OneDrive account.

On the PC (Windows 10) I've moved / deleted some folders / files then it has been sync to the web, but on the laptop (Windows 11), it say that "Your files a synced", but actually it's not.

### Your files are "synced"

[image: Your files are synced]

### Actually, it's not

##### How could I make the laptop to sync with the web and my PC?

[image]